# One-to-many association get data from the one table

Tags: go, one-to-many, go-gorm

I'm new to Golang and Gorm, and I couldn't find the anwswer. In a rest api, I want my json to come with values from the one table relation.

```
type Product struct {
    gorm.Model   
    Name             string       
    Description      string       
    Weight           string
    TypeID           uint
}
type Type struct {
    ID                   string         `gorm:"primaryKey;"`
    Name                 string
    Product              []Product

}
```

and I want my Product json to come with the ID and Name from Type.
but this doesn't work.

```
var product Product
id:=1
db.Preload("Type").First(&product, id)
```

Do I have to do something like this in the struct?

```
type Product struct {
    gorm.Model   
    Name             string       
    Description      string       
    Weight           string
    Type             Type 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to load `Type.ID` and `Type.Name` into `Product.ID` and `Product.Name`, you need to specifically select fields from two tables:

```
var product Product
id:=1
db.Joins("JOIN types ON types.id = products.type_id"). Select("types.id, types.name, products.description, products.weight, products.type_id").First(&product, id)
```

If you want to separate `Type` fields into a separate field in the `Product` struct, you need to make the following changes:

```
type Product struct {
    gorm.Model   
    Name             string       
    Description      string       
    Weight           string
    TypeID           uint
    Type             Type 
}

var product Product
id:=1
db.Preload("Type").First(&product, id)
```

Here, all of the `Type` fields will be loaded into the `Product.Type` field.

Comment: thanks. I will use the second to separate the Type fields.